# How can Julia shell commands set environment variables?

Tags: julia

When I try to set an environment variable in a shell command in the REPL like this:

```
;SOME_ENV="foo" some_command
```

I get an error:

```
zsh:1: command not found: SOME_ENV=foo
```

How can I set environment variables for individual commands?

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use `withenv()`:

```
julia> withenv("SOME_ENV"=>"foo") do
           run(`some_command`)
       end
```

Alternatively, you could use `setenv()`, but it completely replaces the environment, instead of just modifying it like `withenv()` does. In particular, you lose the `PATH` environment variable, so you need to specify the full path of the command:

```
julia> run(setenv(`/path/to/some_command`, "FOO"=>"BAR"))
```

Or you can copy the `PATH` variable into the new environment:

```
julia> run(setenv(`some_command`, "FOO"=>"BAR", "PATH"=>ENV["PATH"]))
```

For more details, see the documentation for [`withenv()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.withenv) and [`setenv()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.setenv).

Comment: Also, you can create `Cmd` with the necessary environment `Cmd(\`some_command\`, env = "FOO" => "BAR")` and run it. In order to preserve existing environment it is useful to copy it `env = copy(ENV); env["FOO"] = "BAR"` and pass it around.